# URL setting in configuration file returns null

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, app-config

I am following this tutorial:

https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/c-sharp/manage-read-configurations-using-configurationmanager-csharp/

For some reason when I try this it always returns `null`.

**Environment.config looks like:**

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="URL" value="http://www.test.com"/>
</appSettings>
```

**My test class looks like:**

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using qa.WrapperFactory;

namespace UnitTestProject2
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            // Sign in through google first, so we don't have to follow new tabs
            BrowserFactory.InitBrowser("Chrome");
            var y = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["URL"];
            BrowserFactory.LoadApplication(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["URL"]);
            BrowserFactory.CloseAllDrivers();
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason I keep getting the error:

> Message: Test method UnitTestProject2.UnitTest1.TestMethod1 threw
>   exception:  System.ArgumentNullException: Argument 'url' cannot be
>   null.

The Browser loads correctly

Comment: Show your App.config file please.

Comment: See Environment.config looks like:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't follow your tutorial properly, if you read *"Steps to read AppSettings from External Config File using ConfigurationManager"* section carefully, you will see:

**Steps to read AppSettings from External Config File using ConfigurationManager:**

**App.config File**

```
<configuration>
        <appSettings configSource="Configurations\Environment.config" />
</configuration>
```

Create another config file and name it Environment.config under the same project.

**Environment.config File**

```
<appSettings>
        <add key="URL" value="http://www.example.com"/>
</appSettings>
```

To read the connection string from the above config file, use the below code:

```
var url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["URL"];
```

You need to add an external `SomeConfigFile.config` file path/reference to your `App.config` file before using `ConfigurationManager.AppSetting["key"]`.

Comment: How would this work with multiple ennvironment. Because now it always looks at the appSettings.config.

But if I have multiple environments how do I set it up?

Because I have under configurations a dir named acceptance and in that folder appSettings.config. But when I select acceptance as an environment I still receive the info from Configurations/appsettings.config and not from configurations/Acceptance/appSettings.config

Comment: @Tester2019 for multiple external config files, you should add them ass well to app.config file.

Comment: like this:

<configuration>
        <appSettings configSource="Configurations\Environment.config" />
        <appSettings configSource="Configurations\acceptance\Environment.config" />
configSource="Configurations\test\Environment.config" />
</configuration>

??

Comment: It gives me the error Cannot initialise configuration system

Comment: I will test it later and let you know, you can do your own research too of course.